# SQLite - replace once part of a string

Tags: sqlite, replace

Is it possible in SQLite to replace once part of a string?

For example

`UPDATE pages SET path = replace(path, '/page', '/article') WHERE path LIKE '/page/%'"`

results to
`/page/page1/page2 => /article/article1/article2`

but I need
`/page/page1/page2 => /article/page1/page2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$l1 = strlen($old_path);
$l2 = $l1+1;
```

and

```
UPDATE pages
SET path = replace(
    substr(path, 1, {$l1}),
    '{$old_path}',
    '{$new_path}'
) || substr(path,{$l2})
WHERE path LIKE '{$old_path}/%'
```

is really helps to me

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like:

```
UPDATE pages SET path = replace(path, '/page/', '/article/') WHERE path LIKE '/page/%'"
```

Comment: But if path is equal to /page/page/page, then this will not help.
And chance of this path exists